# Can I use 1st gen Magic Keyboard for 4th gen 11-inch iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

I wonder if the 1st-gen Magic Keyboard for iPad, which was released in 2020 is compatible with the latest version of iPad Pro. The only source I found is [it may be compatible with 3rd-gen iPad Pro](https://www.imore.com/first-generation-magic-keyboard-works-m1-ipad-pro-after-all), but I'm not sure about the 4th-gen.

Comment: It's a Bluetooth keyboard.  Why wouldn't it work?  Why not try and connect it?